# How can I hide an object's name in chat in LSL?

Tags: linden-scripting-language

Given an object named `MyObject`, an `llSay(0, "Hello World");` from a script inside the object will look like this in chat:

```
MyObject: Hello World
```

How can I get it to just look like this?

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string message = "Hello World!";
// save the old name of the object for later use
string oldname = llGetObjectName();
// get the words (split by spaces) in the message
list messageParts = llParseString2List(message, [" "], []);
// make the objects name the first word of the message.
llSetObjectName(llList2String(messageParts,0));
// delete the first word.
messageParts = llDeleteSubList(messageParts,0,0);
// use an emote to remove the : from the said text
llSay(0, "/me "+llDumpList2String(messageParts, " ");
// set our objects name back to its old text.
llSetObjectName(oldname);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the first word of the string as the object's name may result in some oddnessess with colouring of the chat. A cleaner (and leaner on the limited RAM in LSL) way is to name the object "" instead, like this:

```
// Your message in a string
string message = "Waves crash on the beach";

// Store the current object name to restore it afterwards
string oldName = llGetObjectName();

// Rename the object with a blank string
llSetObjectName("");

// Say the message
llSay(0, "/me " + message);

// Restore the object name
llSetObjectName(oldName);
```

Answer (score 0):

integer ListenHandle;

default
    {

```
state_entry()
    {
    ListenHandle = llListen(1234,"",llGetOwner(),"");       
    }

listen(integer channel, string name, key id, string message)
    {
    list mess = llParseString2List(message,[" "],[]);
    llSetObjectName(llList2String(mess,0));
    mess = llDeleteSubList(mess,0,0);
    message = llDumpList2String(mess," ");
    llSay(0,"/me " + message);
    }
}
```

---

The chat on channel 1234 (for this example) will be displayed in chat (channel 0) without the prefix of name of the object containing the script.

usage:

**/1234 *message to be displayed***

text displayed in chat channel 0:

***message to be displayed***

Comment: You're on the right track here but the example leaves the object named as the first word of the message.

Comment: Just save object name before, and rename to it afterwards.